# Cannot remove bath hardware

Tags: plumbing, hardware

I have hardware in my bathroom that does not have the usual Allen Wrench screw anywhere on it to remove the trim.  I have attached pictures of the hardware.

I don't want to apply too much force in turning the faucet in case I do more damage behind the walls.  I also read they may be pull off but that again makes me wary as to what forces are being applied behind the wall.

Any ideas?[image]